# Are 손가락 and 발가락 related to 숟가락 and 젓가락?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Does 가락 have any meaning by itself? Are 손가락 and 발가락 related to 숟가락 and 잣가락? I can imagine 숟가락 meaning 'round finger (extension)'and 젓가락 meaning 'long finger (extension)'. At least I'll use that to remember this set of words. Do 숟 and 젓 have any meaning by themselves? Google Translate translates 숟 as 'spoon', in which case why is 숟가락 necessary? (I don't want to rely on Google Translate.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-가락` (suffix) denotes bar-like shape that is long and thin, such as fingers. It can also be used as a unit word that can count objects in that shape.

> - 국수 한 가락 (a single thread of noodle)

Naturally, `손가락` and `발가락` represent those bar-shaped parts of `손` and `발`.

Interestingly, it is often used to count songs. This `가락` is a homonym that means a melody.

> - 노래 한 가락 (a song)
> - 구슬픈 가락 (a plaintive melody)

Now regarding `숟가락` and `젓가락`, `가락`s here are from the first meaning above (bar-shaped object).

`숟가락` is combination of `술` and `-가락`. `술` is an old Korean word for spoons that is <s>no longer used today</s> (see below and [K._](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/949/k)
's [comment](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/are-%EC%86%90%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD-and-%EB%B0%9C%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD-related-to-%EC%88%9F%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD-and-%EC%A0%93%EA%B0%80%EB%9D%BD#comment3742_3355)). You might wonder why by combining `술` and `가락` we get `*숟*가락`. <s>This is because of a phonological transformation called 사잇소리.</s> (see below)

Finally, `젓가락` is `저`([箸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AE%B8))+`-가락`. Unlike `술`, `저` here is a Chinese word for chopsticks. Again, see [this link](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/pronunciation-of-%EC%A3%BC%EA%B0%80-stock-price-and-%ED%9A%A8%EA%B3%BC-effect/1770#1770) on 사잇소리 (specifically, 사이시옷 part), if you wonder why we have `ㅅ` between `저` and `-가락`.

*edited*: Today, **`술` as spoon** is used only as a unit word when measuring uncountable substance by a spoon.

> - 밥 한 술 (a spoonful of rice)

*edited*: It is not 사잇소리 phenomenon that `술`+`가락` becomes `숟가락`. There are just some compound words where `ㄹ` at the end of predecessor becomes `ㄷ` sound. See [한글맞춤법](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_orthography) ([article 29](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000071&mn_id=30)) for more examples like this.

Comment: For your Korean kitchen vocabulary: `1 큰(big) 술(spoon)` - `1 tbsp`, `1 작은(small) 술(spoon)` - `1 tsp`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Some Australian Indigenous languages have unit words, and songs (traditionally) and cassette tapes (in modern times) were counted using that word.

Answer (score 1):

(1) 손 - hand, 손가락 - finger

가락 - stick.

( off topic : Here my curiosity is about chop stick. chop stick does
not contain any meaning for meal )

From three word and their relations, 손가락 is
plausible.

(2) 수저 : Tool for eating. Usually, it is union of spoon and chop
stick.

(3) As like hand, 수저가락 (not used in commonly. I introduce for
explaining) indicates 숟가락 or 젓가락.

Conclusion : 손 <-> 수저, thumb, forefinger, ... <-> 숟가라, 젓가락

(4) Frequently, 수저 is used for indicating spoon.